# try_files with a single @location?

Tags: nginx

I started from https://gist.github.com/mattd/1006398 and now I have this:

```
    root /data/example.com;
    location /sites/default/files/ {
            try_files $uri @proxy;
    }
    location / {
            try_files @proxy;
    }
    location @proxy {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8088;
    }
```

Of course, this is not valid syntax. How can I make this work? Basically, I want `sites/default/files` to serve the file directly if it exists and use `@proxy` otherwise. Other directories should go to `@proxy` immediately. I do not want to copy-paste the `@proxy` configuration because a lot more will be added there (caching). I will also have other directories that should be served directly for example `.well-known`.

Comment: Does `/data/example.com` contain `/sites/default/files/`? If so: 1.) Remove the location `location /sites/default/files/ { [...] }` directive. 2.) Add `$uri` to the `try_files` directive in `location / { [...] }`.

Comment: Yes /data/example.com/sites/default/files exists but I don't want /data/example.com/foobar to be served directly only /data/example.com/sites/default/files  .

Comment: @chx you could use `internal;` directive for that purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways to solve the problem:

#### 1

You could put your proxy config to separate file and `include` it.

`proxy_conf`:

```
proxy_pass proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8088;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
# etc.....
```

and your config:

```
location /sites/default/files/ {
   try_files $uri @proxy;
}
location / {
    include proxy_conf;
}
location @proxy {
    include proxy_conf;
}
```

#### 2

Use `error_page` directive:

```
location / {
    error_page 418 = @proxy;
    return 418;
}
```

#### 3

Use *fake* non-existent path as a first argument to `try_files`:

```
location / {
    try_files /NONEXISTENTFILE @proxy;
}
```

Comment: > You could put your proxy config to separate file and include it. - I really like this one and will use it.